# Polynomial looks even at integers

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Let $p$ be a degree $n$ polynomial so that $p(k) = p(-k)$ for all integers $1 \leq k \leq n$ where $n$ is even. Prove that $p(x) = q(x^2)$ for some polynomial $q$.

I want to know if my solution is valid as it is different from the official solution.

**My solution**

Consider $r(x) = p(x) - p(-x)$. Clearly $r$ has roots at all the integers $1 \leq k \leq n$. Either $r$ is identically $0$ or it is not. If it is identically 0 then $p$ is even and we are done. Otherwise, suppose $r \neq 0$. Since it is not $0$ we may write $r(x) = (x-1)\cdots(x-n)$. Then $r(0) = (-1)^nn!$ from its factored representation, but since $r(x) = p(x) - p(-x)$, we see that $r(0) = p(0) - p(0) = 0$. This is a contradiction and so $r$ must be identically $0$.

**Official solution**

The solution given also uses $r(x)$ as defined, but instead they simply notice $r$ is degree $n-1$ and is $0$ at $n$ points and thus is identically $0$.

I'm sure this is valid too, I just want to check the validity of my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it is identically $0$ then $p$ is even and we are done.

You should probably explain this step a little further. You aren't proving that $p$ is even, you are proving that $p=q(x^2)$ for some $q$.

---

> Since it is not $0$ we may write $r(x)=(x−1)⋯(x−n)$

This is not true. You do not know what the leading coefficient of $r$ is. Also, how do you know the degree of $r$ is $n$? For example, how do you know $r(x)$ isn't $x(x-1)\cdots(x-n)$? Note that such a $r$ would invalidate your proof, so you need to show why it is impossible.

---

Overall, the idea of the proof is correct, but you need to iron out the two details.

Comment: For the first, it is a simple proof that even polynomial is $g(x^2)$ for some $g$, since if $f(x) = f(-x)$ then $f(x) - f(-x) = 0$ and so all the coefficients must be zero, but the odd ones would differ by a minus sign so must be zero. For the second, we can say $r(x) = A(x-1)\cdots(x-k)s(x)$ for some $A$, some $k \leq n$, and some $s(x)$ of degree $\leq n-k$. The degree cannot be higher since $r$ is a sum of degree $n$ polynomials. I am not sure now to argue that $r$ has no additional roots.

Comment: @Eulerian you might use the fundamental theorem of algebra, which says that a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots.

Comment: @Eulerian: the degree of $r$ is at most $n$ and it vanishes at $1,2,\dots,n$ so $r(x) =a(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)$. This is based on factor theorem: if $r(c) =0$ then $(x-c) $ is a factor of $r(x) $.